# What is my computer's audio card's DAC bit resolution?

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, operating-systems, bitrate

I know that every sound card converts digital data to analog sound using a [DAC chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter). This chip's quality greatly determines the sound quality.

Is there a way to query parameters such as bit resolution and sample rate from the OS (mine is GNU/Linux)? I know I can search the web for specs / datasheets but I was wondering whether this information is available to the OS.

Comment: Knowing the available parameters doesn't *actually* determine the quality of the DAC itself. Built-in DACs are usually pretty low quality. You could get a bit of a feel for it if you happen to have one that can work at higher bit- & sample-rates 24-bit, 88.2kHz  & upwards. pretty much all of them will do 16-bit 44.1 or 48k. idk nix specifically, but this info should be available to your Sound control panel. These are the options available on a mid-range external DAC, on a Mac - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WZFE.png

Comment: Modern PC means 24bit 192KHz realtek chip with professional layout. Low cost external USB sound cards means 16bit 48KHz with poor layout.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and confirming that this info is at least available to Darwin's kernel - I hope it's available for the Linux' kernel as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to list the capabilities of each of your audio devices: https://gitlab.com/sonida/alsa-capabilities

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).